# Is it possible to insert multiple blocks into a drawing using the Forge Design Automation API?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management, autodesk-designautomation

As the title says I am looking to use the Design Automation API to upload an archive of blocks, then insert them all into a drawing with a border.

The positioning of the blocks does not matter they just need to be inserted into the drawing ready to be arranged by an engineer.

Any help or advice on end points or limitations would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is doable. You need to develop a custom activity with 2 inputs and one output. input#1 is the base drawing with boarder and input#2 is a zip file with the blocks. When you submit your workitem you will mark the second input argument as `ResourceKind` = `ResourceKind.ZipPackage` this will tell the service that it should unzip the file into the folder designated by `LocalFileName`. Then your script can enumerate the files in the folder (see [vl-directory-files](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/AutoCAD-AutoLISP/files/GUID-C28C0CB0-FBBE-4AA8-BAC4-2FF222772514-htm.html)) and issue the INSERT command.